# How to get elements values by class name and store them in an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get values from text boxes that are out of a `<form>` tag.
The three text boxes have the same class name. I want to get their values and use them later.

I am getting error for the alert part in `jQuery` below.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" class="className">
 <input type="text" class="className">
 <input type="text" class="className">
```

**jQuery**

```
 var $j_object = $(".className");
 $j_object.each( function(i){
     alert($j_object[i].val())                      
 });
```

Comment: replace the alert line with `alert($(this).val());   `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `.eq(index)` at this context,

```
var $j_object = $(".className");
$j_object.each( function(i){
  alert($j_object.eq(i).val());                     
});
```

Or you can use the `this` value inside of `.each()` to simplify the task,

```
var $j_object = $(".className");
$j_object.each( function(){
  alert($(this).val());                     
});
```

If you use bracket notation to access the jquery element collection, then that will return plain javascript object. And that won't have jquery functions in its prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the textbox values to array using `.map()` function in jQuery.

**Working Example**

```js
var array = $('.className').map(function(){
  return $(this).val()
}).get();
alert(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="className" value="1">
 <input type="text" class="className" value="2">
 <input type="text" class="className" value="3">
```

Comment: if I have name attribute for the text boxes, can I get the names from the same code you provided?

Comment: Yes. Sure. You can use `$(this).attr('yourAttribute')` instead of  `$(this).val()`

Comment: If you want I can show you a sample demo. So let me know if you need.

Comment: what would be the type of this array in this case??String or int?i just want to append the array with formdata